# Could not connect to the endpoint URL in Cost Explorer

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, botocore

Im trying to use CostExplorer to estimate charges, filtered by TagName.

```
time_period = {'Start':'2017-12-18', 'End':'2017-12-19'}
filters = {
  "And":
    [{
      "Tags": {
        "Key": "TagName",
        "Values": ["Test1"]
      }
    }]
}

print aws.get_cost_and_usage(TimePeriod=time_period, Granularity='DAILY', Metrics=['BlendedCost'], Filter=filters)
```

By requesting the cost of any of my machines (Ireland), it shows an error that it is **not possible to connect to ce.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    print aws.service.cloudwatch.client.get_cost_and_usage(TimePeriod=time_period, Granularity='DAILY', Metrics=['BlendedCost'], Filter=filters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ce.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

Maybe this service is not available in Ireland yet?

I cannot find "Cost explorer" / "Billing" / "Cost management" here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#awssupport_region

I'm using:

> boto3==1.5.2
>
> botocore==1.8.16

Comment: Endpoint availability would be determined by talking with the vendor I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cost Explorer service is deployed in us-east-1.

All of your queries must be directed to that region, i.e.:

```
client = boto3.client('ce', region_name='us-east-1')
client.get_cost_and_usage(....)
```

Response will include all your regions.

Notice the AWS UI also mentions 'Global' when you navigate to billing console.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. 
How do you know it or where do you saw it?

Im looking for documentation...

Comment: Not sure where I encountered it before - possibly on Route53 API documentation which is also located on us-east-1 only.
There is a method for session class thats called  get_available_regions() and is used to describe where a service is deployed, however it returns blank for 'ce'. Some things in life are not perfect :X

Comment: boto3.session.Session().get_available_regions('ec2') returns all regions with ec2 endpoints.
When running same using global services such as 'route53' or 'ce' list returned is empty >> []

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-explorer-api.html